# SQL regular expression to check if a string contains a certain substring

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am using SQL and need to check if a string contains a certain substring using regular expressions. Lower and upper case letters and space are allowed.

Currently, I have 
    Where description = '/^[a-zA-Z\s]*mysubstring[a-zA-Z\s]*$/'

But it is not working for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: Which RDMS are you using?

Comment: It looks like you are not using the pattern correctly. It should look like `WHERE description REGEXP '^[[:alpha:][:space:]]*mysubstring[[:alpha:][:space:]]*$'`

Comment: You can simply use LIKE statement , to check the substring

Comment: @sumit: `WHERE description LIKE '%mysubstring%'` will find entries that may contain more than just letters and whitespace. Ke Zhang, please check what is working for you best.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL regex is not supporting the same syntax as PHP PCRE regex. If you want to use a regex check, you must use the [`REGEXP` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp). Next, it does not support `\s` and other shorthand classes, you need to replace it with a `[:space:]` POSIX character class.

Also, MySQL `REGEXP` will perform a case insensitive regex check by default, but you still can use `[A-Za-z]` just in case you have non-standard options.

Use

```
WHERE description REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z[:space:]]*mysubstring[a-zA-Z[:space:]]*$'
```

If you do not care about what there is in the entries and you just need to find those containing your string, use [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) with `%` (=any text) wildcard:

```
WHERE description LIKE '%mysubstring%'
```